# php exec('echo 1 > ~/cctv_config/cctvstatus') does not work

Tags: php, exec, echo

Here is part of the code that I have in php file:

```
function checkSetStatus($checkSet) {

//other if options here

    if ($checkSet == '2') {
        exec('echo 0 > ~/cctv_config/cctvstatus.log');  
        sleep(1);
        exec('echo "$(date) | setOff" >> weblog.log');
        return (int) exec('cat ~/cctv_config/cctvstatus');
    }
}
```

Problem is with line:

```
exec('echo 0 > ~/cctv_config/cctvstatus.log');
```

When I trigger command

```
echo 0 > ~/cctv_config/cctvstatus.log
```

in linux commandline, it works fine. However if it is triggered indirectly by exec function in php file it does not make any changes in targeted file.

In apache error log file there is infomation that

**file or directory ~/cctv_config/cctvstatus.log can not be created**

(I already changed mode of cctvstatus.log to 777). Similar information is logged as a result of triggering this line:

```
exec('cat ~/cctv_config/cctvstatus');
```

In this case it is logged that such file or directory does not exist (There is one more issue - in exec with cat I am wondering if rather passthru function should not be used).

Comment: Have you tried using `file_put_contents` (+ `FILE_APPEND` flag)? This will give you more information about why it failed, instead of silently ignoring it. It'll give you less issues with escaping etc. Also, `~` stands for the home directory of the current user. As you aren't running PHP as the same user you are using for manually running the command, the directory will not be the same (most likely). I suggest using a full path (eg `/home/user/cctv_config/`).

Comment: Thank you for that. I will be able to verify your suggestions in few hours. I will post an update after that.

Comment: You were right. It was a problem with file path. Changing ~ to /home/myuser/ solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

The home directory of the user of the PHP instance is not the same as the user you are testing the command with.
You are reffering to the home directory by using the `~` (tilde) before the path.

Change the path to the full path instead:

```php
function checkSetStatus($checkSet) {

//other if options here

    if ($checkSet == '2') {
        exec('echo 0 > /home/myuser/cctv_config/cctvstatus.log');  
        sleep(1);
        exec('echo "$(date) | setOff" >> weblog.log');
        return (int) exec('cat /home/myuser/cctv_config/cctvstatus');
    }
}
```